# Find rotation angle of point that two points have given slope $m$.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, rotations

I have a problem in finding a rotation angle.

Given:

- Coordinates of P1
- Coordinates of P2 in unrotated state
- Slope $m$

To calculate:

- angle $\theta$ to rotate the Point P2 that the slope between P1 and P2 has a given value.

I already have a solution but this solution can be found only numerically and I need a way to find a solution without some root finding algorithm or something like this.

Here what I tried:

Formula of slope is defined as:

$$m = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

$x_2$ and $y_2$ can be defined as a rotation function with degree of freedom $\theta$:

$$x_2' = x_2*\cos(\theta) - y_2*\sin(\theta)$$

$$y_2' = y_2*\cos(\theta) + x_2*\sin(\theta)$$

where $x_2$ and $y_2$ are the coordinates in the unrotated (start) position and $x_2'$ and $y_2'$ are the coordinates in the searched target position.

If I put this in the equation of the slope $m$ I receive:

$$m = \frac{y_2*\cos(\theta) + x_2*\sin(\theta)-y_1}{x_2*\cos(\theta) - y_2*\sin(\theta)-x_1}$$

Since $m$ is known I can now find a solution of $\theta$.

But I solved this only with root finding algorithm and that is not what I want. Is there a way to solve this in a unique way analytically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT...after rearranging you will have $$\cos\theta(mx_2-y_2)-\sin\theta(my_2+x_2)=mx_1-y_1$$
This is an equation of the form $$a\cos\theta-b\sin\theta=c$$ which can be solved by standard means such as a compound angle transformation - i.e. rewrite the left-hand side as $$R\cos(\theta+\alpha)$$

Comment: Thank you that worked! :) Great!

Comment: @ryang thanks for the hint. Sorry about that.